# How to automatically find connected network adapters & turn on ICS Using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I Want to make an hotspot application but the main issue i have is that ICS Can't be turned on automatically.I Have searched whole internet over this question but didn't found something helpfull.Came here with a hope that i can get some help here.

Answer (score -1):

You must not have looked very hard.

```
Private Function EnableDisableICS(ByVal sPublicConnectionName As String, ByVal sPrivateConnectionName As String, ByVal bEnable As Boolean)  
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim oNetSharingManager, oConnectionCollection, oItem, EveryConnection, objNCProps
oNetSharingManager = CreateObject("HNetCfg.HNetShare.1")
oConnectionCollection = oNetSharingManager.EnumEveryConnection
For Each oItem In oConnectionCollection
    EveryConnection = oNetSharingManager.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection(oItem)
    objNCProps = oNetSharingManager.NetConnectionProps(oItem)
    If objNCProps.name = sPrivateConnectionName Then
        bFound = True
        MsgBox("Starting Internet Sharing For: " & objNCProps.name)
        If bEnable Then
            EveryConnection.EnableSharing(1)
        Else
            EveryConnection.DisableSharing()
        End If
    End If
Next
oConnectionCollection = oNetSharingManager.EnumEveryConnection
For Each oItem In oConnectionCollection
    EveryConnection = oNetSharingManager.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection(oItem)
    objNCProps = oNetSharingManager.NetConnectionProps(oItem)
    If objNCProps.name = sPublicConnectionName Then
        bFound = True
        MsgBox("Internet Sharing Success For: " & objNCProps.name)
        If bEnable Then
            EveryConnection.EnableSharing(0)
        Else
            EveryConnection.DisableSharing()
        End If
    End If
Next
Return Nothing 'bEnable & bFound
End Function  

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As      System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    EnableDisableICS("YOUR ACTIVE NETWORK", "YOUR ADAPTOR TO SHARE", True)
End Sub
```

That came directly off of [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/470319/how-to-enable-internet-connection-sharing-using-command-line)

Comment: Is there any steps by step guide that what type of ui & toolbox items i should add to make it work ?